# stop currently running bash script lazily/gracefully

Tags: bash

Say I have a bash script like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
exec-program zero
exec-program one
```

the script issued a run command to exec-program with the arg "zero", right? say, for instance, the first line is currently running. I know that Ctrl-C will halt the process and discontinue executing the remainder of the script.

Instead, is there a keypress that will allow the current-line to finish executing and then discontinue the script execution (not execute "exec-program one") (without modifying the script directly)? In this example it would continue running "exec-program zero" but after would return to the shell rather than immediately halting "exec-program zero"

TL;DR Something runtime similar to "Ctrl-C" but more lazy/graceful ??

Comment: ah I just realized that in some cases Ctrl-C will actually halt the first line but then continue the script. This is surprising behavior...

Comment: You should look into `trap` which allows you to catch signals (such as Ctrl+C's generated `SIGINT`) and handle them programaticly. `trap` with some control flow will probably get you where you want to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the man page, under SIGNALS section it reads:

> If bash is waiting for a command to complete and receives a signal for which a trap has been set, the trap will not be executed until the command completes.

This is exactly what you're asking for. You need to set an exit trap for SIGINT, then run `exec-program` in a subshell where SIGINT is ignored; so that it'll inherit the SIG_IGN handler and <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> won't kill it. Below is an implementation of this concept.

```
#!/bin/bash -
trap exit INT
foo() (
  trap '' INT
  exec "$@"
)

foo sleep 5
echo alive
```

If you hit <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> while `sleep 5` is running, bash will wait for it to complete and then exit; you will not see `alive` on the terminal.

`exec` is for avoiding another fork() btw.

Comment: it would be nice if this behavior was built into the shell under a specific keypress but at least this way the behavior will be portable. I can use a different SIGNAL than Ctrl-C right? I don't want to replace the behavior of Ctrl-C... maybe Ctrl+Y ??